# Choose Non-default googlecalendar with google-java-client-api

Tags: java, android, api, events, calendar

I want to get all the Calendars, which are in my GoogleAccount, using the google java client API.

In my application I want that a user can choose in wich calendar his events will be saved (not only in the default). But therefore I need their CalendarIDs. I don't want that the users have to search their calendar ids to write them by hand into the app.

Would it be possible to create a new Calendar in his account, to write all the events in this new one.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I solved the problem. The new help is much better.

Comment: What do you mean by new help? As soon as possible, can you answer and accept that answer yourself? It ok and recommended. Keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible.You only have to know the calendarId in which you want to save the new event, and use them with the event insert function.

For example :

```
Event event = new Event();

event.setSummary("This is my Event");
event.setLocation("127.0.0.1 -- Home sweet Home!!");

ArrayList<EventAttendee> participants = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
participants .add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("member@domain.com"));
event.setAttendees(participants);

DateTime start = new DateTime(new Date(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));

DateTime end = new DateTime(new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("YourCalendarID", event).execute();
```

Hope this could help you!